# Get and set internal data: return type, behaviour in case of error

Tags: c++

Given is a C++ class holding internal data that shall be exposed to the outside and that shall be also modifiable.

```
class Container {
  public:
    ... get( int key ) const;
    ... set( int key, int value );
  private:
    std::vector<int> m_values;
};
```

The question is what return type `get()` and `set()` preferably get. For `get()`:

1. `const int& get( key )`, reference to const value.
2. `const int* get( key )`, pointer to const value.

When using the reference, something must happen when the given key does not exist in the container. Exception? Or just access `m_values` and let it throw? Rely on `assert`s?

The pointer return type can return `nullptr` indicating an invalid operation. However wouldn't this mean the caller did something wrong in general by requesting something that isn't there?

For `set()`:

1. `void set( key, value )`
2. `bool set( key, value )`

The `void` version ignores invalid keys or values. Again: What to do in case of an error?

The `bool` version returns `true` on success and `false` when key and/or value are invalid. Also the same as for `get()` here: The user probably did something wrong when specifying an invalid key and/or value.

Would you rather let the application crash somehow to indicate the user used it wrong or rely on the user checking result return values?

Comment: Considering std::vector already has a simple `get & set` that doesn't do lot of error checking .. I would handle some in your `Container`

Comment: @parapurarajkumar `std::vector` is of course only an example, and it doesn't do much error-checking like you said, so you (as the user) have to check if what you're doing with it is correct. That's probably exactly the question I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you considered throwing `std::invalid_argument` if `key` is bad?

Comment: @moshbear Yes, and I'm asking myself if that's a good style of doing it. If `get()` throws, there must be some `has( key )` method to check for a valid key, which also means that both `has()` and `get()` *internally* check for a correct key, which might get expensive in complex containers. Or am I too much worried about *premature optimization*? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For the getter, I would also consider returning by value.  Returning a pointer (yuk) or a reference limits options to reimplement the internals of your class at a later date unless you're happy to also make interface changes.

As a contrived example, consider:

```
class Person
{
public:
    // Returns height in metres
    const int &getHeight() const { return height; }

private:
    int height;  // Height in metres
};
```

Now at a later date, what if we decide to change the internals to store the height in millimetres?  We can't do this:

```
const int &getHeight() const { return height / 1000; }
```

As for the setter, well, it's really up to you to decide what to do on failure.

Comment: Returning by value is fine as long as you don't want to *store references* to the objects. In my example with `int`s it's just fine, but `Container` might hold objects that are being referenced elsewhere.

Comment: @Tank: Indeed; I'm not saying that by-value is the *best* choice, merely that you should consider it as an option.